# Asp.net core 2 with angular 6 template

Tags: asp.net, angular6

I am looking for a template to use asp.net core 2.0 with angular 6 in one solution with f5 hit to run the application.

Can you help find such request ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any working project?i'm looking too

Comment: I found 2 templates in github but all of them have some doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one, it is on GitHub, it could be a good starting point but it is not perfect, it should grow and evolve during next months...

https://github.com/JuanGarciaCarmona/AspNetCore21Ang6Template

Also there is an article in Code Project that explains how to use it.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1246748/Angular-within-ASP-NET-Core

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have proceeded with one commercial template already.

Answer (score 2):

tutorial 
[here:](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1432/aspnet-core-apps-using-angular-cli-template)
I would not use

```
Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0-rc1-final
```

but

```
Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0
```

You can use **Angular6**.

The magic is that .net core **starts new command line** itself and **runs npm script**.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

`npm start` is by default alias for `ng serve`.

I do have working project with Angular6 and Core 2.

My project.csproj

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

  <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

and Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;


namespace AngularSPA
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But I only have aesthetic problem with built-in command line, you can see my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274171/angular-6-with-asp-net-core-internal-cmd-not-working-properly).

Comment: Were you able to enable SSR in your project?

Comment: I didn't need that. I have closed app and "public" page is only login page.

Comment: Ok, any help regarding this would be really appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401415/angular-cli-6-ng-build-doesnt-produce-server-bundles