# Angular 6 with ASP.NET Core, internal CMD not working properly

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, angular6, asp-net-core-spa-services

Hello I have **Angular 6** project with **ASP.NET Core 2.0.** backend.
Working in Visual Studio.
**No server side rendering, just SPA.**

When i run my project (F5), `ng serve` command automatically called by .Net, code below.

Produces new command line window, but it seems like **the styles (line rewriting, text progress bars,...) not working.**

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Text stops rendering, but Angular **works**, and I can't see any output.
[image: Weird CMD created by VS]

**Normal behavior: in CMD called** `ng serve`

[image: Good CMD behavior]

**IMPORTANT:**

**BOTH solutions WORK**, **no difference**, but I **can't debug my errors**

Is there some way to fix this? to make VS CMD do the same like mine normal CMD?

Solution does't need to be related to Angular stuff.

Thanks for your time.

Lubos

Comment: it doesn't work the same way when I try to run "dotnet run" from my command line