# Angular CLI 6 - ng build doesn't produce Server bundles

Tags: angular-cli, asp.net-core-2.0, angular-universal, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I am following the official Angular Universal guide available at

https://angular.io/guide/universal

but when I run `ng build --prod` it does produce client bundles but doesn't produce server bundles.

Since my environment is ASP.Net Core, I have skipped `Universal Webpack configuration` and `server.ts`.

With previous version of Angular CLI we were able to build server bundle by specifying app while building `ng build --app=ssr`

Am I missing something? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Show you angular.json and package.json files maybe

Answer (score 1):

### Fix: One thing though, the update process did not bring over the field `deployUrl`, which caused my app to not be able find the bundles when running node dist/server.js. So I added it back in angular.json and it worked. Not sure if this is similar to your case.

Edit2: So, the updated build-angular:server is optimized to generate only the needed code for server-side rendering. So there isn't a need to generate bundles  such as `scripts.15e6d454b35fa67e195e.js` or `polyfills.7f343fe54490ee5246c8.js`, they are embedded in the `main.js`.

---

Edit: I just realized that due to the many changes of the compiling process, using build-angular:browser will not generate a server-side compatible bundle. (multiple reference of window is present)

---

In Angular 6, they opted for a different builder which uses:

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",`

Using this builder these fields are somehow not available. I'm not sure whether it is a bug that the server build config doesn't extend from our main app or there are reasons that we're should not be specifying these fields for `build-angular:server`.

```
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"assets": [
  // Your assets
],
"styles": [
  // Your global styles
],
"scripts": [
  // Your global scripts
]
```

A workaround to make Angular Universal work as before Angular 6 is to use the browser builder to bundle your server app.

You should be familiar with the process, simply copy your configurations from `"architect/build"` and replace the fields that are related to server-side.

e.g.:

```
"outputPath": "dist/server",
"main": "src/main.server.ts",
"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
```

Note: You should disable output hashing either by CLI arguments or changing your configurations for server in `angular.json` to that your server.ts can reference the entry